# "[aria-hidden="true"] elements contain focusable descendents"; best way to fix that?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I have a simple accordion:

```html
<div>
  <button aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='content'>
    Open accordion
  </button>
  <div id='content' aria-hidden='true'>
    This the accordion's hidden content.
  </div>
</div>
```

I use Javascript to open/close the accordion and set the `aria-*` tags.

Everything works fine but when I add links inside the content:

```html
<div>
  <button aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='content'>
    Open accordion
  </button>
  <div id='content' aria-hidden='true'>
    This is the accordion's hidden content.
    <a href='https://www.google.com'>Go to Google</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lighthouse gives me this:

```
[aria-hidden="true"] elements contain focusable descendents
```

It seems to me that adding `tabindex='-1'` to the `a` tag solves the issue:

```html
<a tabindex='-1' href='https://www.google.com'>Go to Google</a>
```

However, that makes the element "non-tabbable", which is not good for accessibility.

I could use JavaScript to manually query for all `a` tags inside an accordion's content but I am not even sure if this really solves the "issue" or is a dirty work-around? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Its quite simple and straight, I guess. The link should be only focusable when it is in the aria-hidden=false that means visible state. So when ever you are opening the tab set aria-hidden=false, I think that will solve the issue, there is no need to add tab-index in a tag as aria-hidden true or false manage that already

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Why are you getting this warning?

This warning shows despite your use of `aria-hidden="true"` the majority of screen readers will ignore `aria-hidden="true"` on a parent item if the children can receive focus (to account for developer mistakes, JavaScript not loading correctly etc.).

### How to fix it?

I am assuming that you are using something like a slide-up animation or similar which is why you don't simply use `display: none` on the content.

If you aren't using an animation then just `display: none` the content when you have `aria-hidden="true"` applied (@Adam has shown you the perfect way to do that in his answer).

Better yet you could just straight up use `display: none` on the div as this would hide all the content from a screen reader anyway so you wouldn't need to use WAI-ARIA there!

#### I am using an animation / transition so can't just hide all the content.

If you are using an animation, opacity changes etc., that stop you simply hiding the entire content then what you can do is to hide the focusable content within the content `<div>`.

We can do this using CSS when you have `aria-hidden="true"` applied, then unhide the focusable elements when when you change or remove `aria-hidden="true"`.

Also to avoid "layout jank" when we unhide the elements again I would suggest using `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none` as that leaves the space allocated for the hidden items and still hides them from screen readers etc.

```css
#content[aria-hidden=true] a[href],
#content[aria-hidden=true] area[href], 
#content[aria-hidden=true] input:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] select:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] textarea:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] button:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] [tabindex]:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] [contenteditable=true]:not([disabled]){
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

### A quick Demo

The easiest way to see what I mean is with a quick demo, press the "Toggle aria-hidden on" button and it will hide all of the focusable elements in the `#content <div>`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#toggle-aria');
var contentDiv = document.querySelector('#content');


btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var self = this;
    if(contentDiv.getAttribute('aria-hidden') == "false"){
      self.innerHTML = "Toggle aria-hidden off";
      contentDiv.setAttribute('aria-hidden', "true"); 
    }else{
      self.innerHTML = "Toggle aria-hidden on";
      contentDiv.setAttribute('aria-hidden', "false"); 
    }
});
```

```css
#content{
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #333;
}

#content[aria-hidden=true] a[href],
#content[aria-hidden=true] area[href], 
#content[aria-hidden=true] input:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] select:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] textarea:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] button:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] [tabindex]:not([disabled]), 
#content[aria-hidden=true] [contenteditable=true]:not([disabled]){
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><button id="toggle-aria">Toggle aria-hidden on</button>

<p>When aria-hidden is set to true on the below div all focusable elements should disappear.</p>

<hr/>

<div id="content" aria-hidden="false">
    <a href="https://google.com">To Google</a><br/><br/>
    <label>An input
      <input />
    </label><br/><br/>
    <label>A Select 
      <select>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
      </select>
     </label><br/><br/>
     <label>A textarea
      <textarea></textarea>
    </label><br/><br/>
    <button>A button</button><br/><br/>
    <div tabindex="0">A fake button with tabindex</div><br/><br/>
    <div contenteditable="true">A div that is cotnent editable</div><br/><br/>
    <p>Only the labels and this paragraph should be the only things left showing when you toggle the aria-hidden to true</p>
    
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button>I am a button purely so you can see there is nothing focusable within the #content div if you "Tab"</button>
```

**Important note:** The second you press the "open accordion" button you should remove `aria-hidden` **before** any animations etc. This is because screen reader users will then try and <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or navigate via screen reader shortcuts) into the content. If you remove `aria-hidden="true"` too late they may skip right past all the content!

Comment: yep i was using animations. thank you so much!!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Comment: What you did here is just fantastic. Like why didn't I think about it?

Comment: thanks @FaizaanKhan, glad you found it useful!

Comment: Elements with the explicit [aria-hidden=true] attribute can be hidden with a wildcard:
*[aria-hidden="true"] {visibility:hidden;} since the visibility is dependent entirely on the "true" state.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution, use CSS `display:none` property to remove the element from being focusable :

```
#content[aria-hidden=true] {
   display:none;
}
```

That's not only useful but quite necessary as we don't want screenreaders to announce non visible things.